# Attach to a Socket.io server instance in a background task

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I am using Socket.io in conjunction with Express in my web application like this:

```
var server = express();
var http = require('http').Server(server);
io = require('socket.io')(http);
...
server.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

http.listen(server.get('port'), function() {
    console.log('Listening on port ' + server.get('port'));
});
```

This works totally fine. However, I am using Kue (a job queue system) to queue up web workers in a totally separate thread. I need to emit messages to clients attached to the socket.io instance shown above from the web worker. I am pretty stuck.

Does anyone know how to do this?